# Почему у JavaFX Node неправильные размеры в методе initialize?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть VBox, который хранит несколько AnchorPane. Для красоты я решил добавить css стиль на этот AnchorPane: -fx-border-width. Но VBox расположен внутри другой AnchorPane, а он соответственно внутри ScrollPane. И я обнаружил, что после добавления стиля, у меня отображаются не все элементы в ScrollPane.
Для тестирования я сделал border-width 0 0 10 0, у меня 20 элементов, таким образом, общий размер VBox после применения стиля к каждому элементу VBox должен увеличиться на 200. В методе контроллера `intiailize()` после вызова родительского layout и applyCss, getHeight() для VBox возвращает 1200. Затем для родительского anchorPane я ставлю высоту `anchorPane.setPrefHeight(vbox.getHeight())`. Но после того как мое приложение окончательно запустится, я вижу, что размер VBox 1400, как и ожидалось. Но размер AnchorPane остается 1200, и поэтому доскроллив до конца, некоторые элементы из ScrollPane не будут видны пользователю. Почему так и как это исправить?

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        addElementsToVBox();
    }

    vbox.applyCss();
    vbox.layout();

    mainAnchorPane.applyCss();
    mainAnchorPane.layout();

    System.out.println(vbox.getHeight()); //тут выдает высоту 1200, 
    //но если после окончательного запуска приложения сделать например кнопку, 
    //и в ее методе onAction() выводить vbox.getHeight(), то будет 1400

    mainAnchorPane.setPrefHeight(vbox.getHeight());
}

private void addElementsToVBox() {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText("Test");
    
    AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    anchorPane.getChildren().add(label);
    anchorPane.setPadding( new Insets(2, 0, 2, 0) );
    anchorPane.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0 0 10 0; -fx-border-color: black");
    anchorPane.applyCss();
    anchorPane.layout();

    vbox.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
}
```

Comment: Нет кода, нет проблемы.

Comment: Добавил код, хотя изначально не добавлял, потому что думал что это теоретический вопрос, и он тут особо не нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в SceneBuilder у меня был заранее выставлен pref height. Из-за этого в `intialize()` я был вынужден использовать `mainAnchorPane.setPrefHeight(vbox.getHeight())`. Если же для mainAnchorPane для всех полей размеров выставить *USE_COMPUTED_SIZE*, а `setPrefHeight()` убрать из `intialize()`, то размер посчитается автоматически, и он будет правильным (1400 в моем случае).